# What would cause a js event handler to only trigger once unless logging the event variable?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, asp.net-core-6.0

On getting an event listener for a button working, I've run into an issue where mystically the anonymous function only runs once unless multiple log statements are used (or if a single log statement including the event variable is included). I've checked, and the 'once' option functions independently of this behavior, as well as ensuring the DOM content is loaded first. Is there something specific to the event system that under the right conditions would necessitate multiple statements within the anonymous function, or a single log of the event itself?

For example:

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("sample text");
});
```

results in a single firing, with the button not triggering any more logs afterward.

when replacing with:

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

the event will fire all day.

I've found putting multiple statements also allows for the event to fire more than once, such as

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("x");
    console.log("y");
});
```

and even placing the statements in separate events:

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("x");
});
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("y");
});
```

will allow for multiple firings of the click event. However even with two separate event listeners there still needs to be more than one log statement, or a single log statement that uses the event variable.

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("x");
}, {once: false});
```

does not result in more than one firing or otherwise resolve the issue. Is there something specific that could be happening within the event system that would necessitate multiple statements within the anonymous function, or a single log of the event itself? The button is not being replaced/modified in the code at all.

Comment: I can't think of any reason for this. I suspect there's more to the problem that you're showing. Maybe related to how you're using ASP.Net, which you included in the tags, but not the code snippets?

Comment: It may be something specific to the runtime environment, though the only other thing I do in the js script is set up a SignalR connection

Comment: Unless you can provide a [mre] it's going to be hard to answer this.